# How to create a nested table in HTML

Tags: html

I am new in HTML can someone please help me here?

This is the required output:

[image]

But I am getting this output:

[image]

I just started to learn nested tables, now I am stuck here.
I tried different variation, changed the code [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H52tO.png) is the closest I've reached. My teacher has been less than useless, keeps avoiding the question. I think this is happening due because I had a mistake in writing any of the tags, I'll be glad if anyone could help me out.

Here is the imag(4).jpg which I've mentioned in the code.

### [image]

**Here is my code:**

```html
<html>

    <head>
        <title>
            Nested Table
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <caption>Container Table</caption>
        <table border = "5" bordercolor = "red">


            <tr>

                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr> <th colspan = "2">Nested Table 2</th> </tr>
                        <tr> <th>Column 1</th> <th>Column 2</th></tr>
                        <tr> <td colspan = "2">Our First Table Nested Within</td> </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr> <th>Nested Table 2</th> </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>List Object 1</li>
                                    <li>List Object 2</li>
                                    <li>List Object 3</li>
                                </ul>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </td>

            </tr>
            
            <tr>

                <td>
                    <tabe>

                        <tr>
                            <th colspan = "2" align="center">Nested Table 3</th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td><a href = "https://www.google.com/">Nested Table</a> </td><td>Demo Continued</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tabe>
                </td>
  
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr><th>Nested Table 4</th></tr>
                        <tr><td><img src = "imag(4).jpg" height="120px" width="120px" alt="Sorry Image could not be displayed"></td></tr>
                    </table>

                </td>

            </tr>


        </table>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: post your required and actual output here on the site and not as an image.

Comment: This is the kind of problems where [HTML validators](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) come in handy. Give it a try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it. There were a few typos in your third nested `<table>` which was causing the issue. It was a incorrectly named table tag `<tabe></tabe>`.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Nested Table
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <caption>Container Table</caption>
        <!-- Parent Table -->
        <table border = "5" bordercolor = "red">
          <tr>
              <td>
                <!-- Nested Table 1 -->
                <table>
                      <tr> 
                        <th colspan = "2">Nested Table 1</th> </tr>
                       <tr> 
                        <th>Column 1</th> <th>Column 2</th></tr>
                       <tr> 
                        <td colspan = "2">Our First Table Nested Within</td> 
                       </tr>
                  </table>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <!-- Nested Table 3 -->
                  <table>
                      <tr> <th>Nested Table 2</th> </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>
                              <ul>
                                  <li>List Object 1</li>
                                  <li>List Object 2</li>
                                  <li>List Object 3</li>
                              </ul>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                  </table>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>
                  <!-- Nested Table 3 -->
                  <table>
                      <tr>
                          <th colspan = "2" align="center">Nested Table 3</th>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td><a href = "https://www.google.com/">Nested Table</a> </td><td>Demo Continued</td>
                      </tr>
                  </table>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <!-- Nested Table 4 -->
                  <table>
                      <tr><th>Nested Table 4</th></tr>
                      <tr><td><img src = "imag(4).jpg" height="120px" width="120px" alt="Sorry Image could not be displayed"></td></tr>
                  </table>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
</html>
```